# How to find related Win32_PnpSignedDriver instance?

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

To get a list of current devices and their drivers I can do the following with Powershell on Windows:

```
> $drvdev = gwmi Win32_SystemDriverPnpEntity
```

and then examine the returned `Win32_SystemDriver` and `Win32_PnpEntity`:

```
> [wmi] $drvdev[49].Antecedent
...
__GENUS                     : 2
__CLASS                     : Win32_PnPEntity
__SUPERCLASS                : CIM_LogicalDevice
...

> [wmi] $drvdev[49].Dependent | fl *
...
Status                  : OK
Name                    : MEIx64
State                   : Running
ExitCode                : 0
Started                 : True
ServiceSpecificExitCode : 0
__GENUS                 : 2
__CLASS                 : Win32_SystemDriver
__SUPERCLASS            : Win32_BaseService
__DYNASTY               : CIM_ManagedSystemElement
__RELPATH               : Win32_SystemDriver.Name="MEIx64"
__PROPERTY_COUNT        : 22
__DERIVATION            : {Win32_BaseService, CIM_Service, CIM_LogicalElement, CIM_ManagedSystemElement}
__NAMESPACE             : root\cimv2
__PATH                  : \\HOMESRV2\root\cimv2:Win32_SystemDriver.Name="MEIx64"
AcceptPause             : False
AcceptStop              : True
Caption                 : Intel(R) Management Engine Interface
CreationClassName       : Win32_SystemDriver
Description             : Intel(R) Management Engine Interface...
```

But in addition to the info returned in the `Win32_SystemDriver` above, there is more information about this driver in the `Win32_PnpSignedDriver` class:

```
> $pnpdrv = gwmi Win32_PnpSignedDriver
> $pnpdrv[86]
__GENUS                 : 2
__CLASS                 : Win32_PnPSignedDriver
__SUPERCLASS            : CIM_Service
__DYNASTY               : CIM_ManagedSystemElement
__RELPATH               :
__PROPERTY_COUNT        : 28
__DERIVATION            : {CIM_Service, CIM_LogicalElement, CIM_ManagedSystemElement}
__NAMESPACE             : root\cimv2
__PATH                  :
Caption                 :
ClassGuid               : {4d36e97d-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
CompatID                : PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E3A&REV_04
CreationClassName       :
Description             : Intel(R) Management Engine Interface
DeviceClass             : SYSTEM
DeviceID                : PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E3A&SUBSYS_84CA1043&REV_04\3&11583659&0&B0
DeviceName              : Intel(R) Management Engine Interface
...
```

Which is the correct way to find any corresponding `Win32_PnpSignedDriver` instance when I start from the `Win32_SystemDriver/PnpEntity` pair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insisting upon your approach, feasible for a *nonrecurring use* (one time hit):

```
$drvdev = gwmi Win32_SystemDriverPnpEntity

# examine the returned Win32_PnpEntity
[wmi] $drvdev[49].Antecedent

# examine the returned Win32_SystemDriver
[wmi] $drvdev[49].Dependent | Format-List -Property *

# a way to find any corresponding Win32_PnpSignedDriver instance
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PnpSignedDriver -Filter `
    "DeviceId = '$(([wmi]$drvdev[49].Antecedent).DeviceId.Replace('\','\\'))'"
```

However, you could apply the [`ASSOCIATORS OF` Statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/associators-of-statement) of the [WMI Query Language (WQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/wql-sql-for-wmi), 
e.g. as follows:

```
$devices = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PnPEntity | ForEach-Object {
    $Win32_PnPEntity = $_
    $Query = "ASSOCIATORS OF " +
             "{Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID='$($Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID)'}" +
             " WHERE AssocClass = Win32_SystemDriverPnpEntity"
    Get-WmiObject -Query $Query -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
        ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Name            = $PSItem.Name;
                SystemDriver    = $PSItem.DisplayName;
                PnPEntity       = $Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID;
            }
    }
}
### Add properties from the "Win32_PnpSignedDriver" class ###
$PnpSignedDrivers = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PnpSignedDriver
foreach ( $device in $devices ) {
   $device |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name PnpSignedDriver -Value $(
        $PnpSignedDrivers | 
            Where-Object {$_.DeviceId -eq $device.PnPEntity} |
            ForEach-Object { if ( $_.FriendlyName) 
                { $_.FriendlyName } else { "== $($_. DeviceName)" }

            }     
    )
}
$devices
```

**Sample output**, sorted and truncated (using `Select-Object -first 5`):

```
PS D:\PShell> $devices = D:\PShell\SU\1439079.ps1
PS D:\PShell> $devices | Sort-Object -Property SystemDriver |
>>         Select-Object -First 5 -Property Name,
>>             SystemDriver, PnpSignedDriver, PnPEntity
```

> ```
> Name         SystemDriver                    PnpSignedDriver                         PnPEntity
> ----         ------------                    ---------------                         ---------
> BasicDisplay BasicDisplay                    == Microsoft Basic Display Driver       ROOT\BASICDISPLAY\0000
> BasicRender  BasicRender                     == Microsoft Basic Render Driver        ROOT\BASICRENDER\0000
> cdrom        CD-ROM Driver                   TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-224DB                SCSI\CDROM&VEN_TSSTCORP&PROD_CDDVDW_...
> CompositeBus Composite Bus Enumerator Driver == Composite Bus Enumerator             ROOT\COMPOSITEBUS\0000
> disk         Disk Driver                     KINGSTON SHFS37A120G                    SCSI\DISK&VEN_&PROD_KINGSTON_SHFS37A...
> ```

Comment: It looks like your script finds the PnpEntity/SystemDriver pair, which I already do (in another way) as described in my question. But I want to also find any Win32_PnpSignedDriver instance when/if it is available and I don't see that in your script?

Comment: @mikewse Answer updated.

Comment: Great thanks - I see now that the DeviceID column is used for mapping in the Win32_PnpSignedDriver instances. Marking as answer!